# Make some options in a select menu "unselectable"

Tags: html, html-select

I have a `select` element with a few options, but I want some of the options to not be selectable.

Basically it's like this:

```
<select>
    <option> CITY 1 </option>
    <option> City 1 branch A </option>
    <option> City 1 branch B </option>
    <option> City 1 branch C </option>
    <option> CITY 2 </option>
    <option> City 2 branch A </option>
    <option> City 2 branch B </option>
    ...
</select>
```

So as you can see, I don't want the cities do be directly selectable, but only the options that come under each city.

How can it be done that the user can click on `CITY 1` or `CITY 2` but it won't be selected, so the user is forced to choose one of the branches underneath?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You're probably looking for an [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup):

```html
<select>
    <optgroup label="CITY 1">
        <option>City 1 branch A</option>
        <option>City 1 branch B</option>
        <option>City 1 branch C</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="CITY 2">
        <option>City 2 branch A</option>
        <option>City 2 branch B</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zg9Mw/**

If you do need to make regular `<option>` elements unselectable, you can give them the `disabled` attribute (it's a boolean attribute, so the value doesn't matter at all):

```
<option disabled>City 2 branch A</option>
```

Comment: wow! I've been doing web development for 10 years and I didn't know there was an element called "optgroup"! Thanks!

Comment: upvote for teaching me something new (after 20 years of HTML coding) :)

Comment: Lol I found the `optgroup` from inspectioning [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com). Important: if you ever plan to make your HTML XML-validated, make sure you use `disabled="disabled"`, and not `disabled` only.

Comment: I've seen `optgroup` element a long time ago (i think phpBB forums used it to group subcategories under categories inside dropdown) and totally forgot about it... thanx a million, saved my day

Answer (score 39):

I can see from your question the previous answers to mine are in fact what uyou are looking for, however just to note for future people coming to this StackOverflow question alike myself looking for a similar answer they can simple type 'Disabled' in an option.

```html
<select>
  <option value="apple" disabled>Apple</option>
  <option value="peach">Peach</option>
  <option value="pear">Pear</option>
  <option disabled="true" value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EAV6y/8/)

Comment: Note that `disabled` doesn't actually have a value, its presence is what makes the element `disabled`. `disabled=""`, `disabled="false"`, and just `disabled` all have the same effect.

Answer (score 19):

From :[How to show disable HTML select option in by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033922/how-to-show-disable-html-select-option-in-by-default?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

This is another way of doing the same thing.

EDIT: (now you are able to run it here)

```html
<label>Unreal :</label>
<select name="unreal">
   <option style="display:none">Select One</option>
   <option>Money</option>
   <option>Country</option>
   <option>God</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think OP wants elements that are *visible* but not selectable.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes correct, and if you try my method, at first it will be visible, but when you click the select button, You will not be able to select the first option. The option itself will not be visible anymore.
Give it a shot.

Comment: @TobySpeight give the snippet a go.

Comment: I tried it, but it's still not what's wanted - whilst it's useful for some things, I never made your version work for the question's `CITY 2` header that's not the first element - that is always invisible.  It seems much better to use an `optgroup` element, or the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: I just reread the question again, and i guest you are right. Should i change my answer, or totally delete it?

Comment: Depsite not what being OP asked, this is what I needed :)

Answer (score 11):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/uuppr/)***

You would use an [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)

```
<select>
 <optgroup label="City 1">
  <option>City 1 Branch A</option>
  <option>City 1 Branch B</option>
  <option>City 1 Branch C</option>
 </optgroup> 
 <optgroup label="City 2">
  <option>City 2 Branch A</option>
  <option>City 2 Branch B</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of option to make this happens, I recommend a plugin of jquery named  Chosen:

It will be like:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select chose-select-width-custom" multiple tabindex="4" name="countryDigestValues">                                             <option value=""></option>                                                                  
  <optgroup class="custom-optgroup-class" label="Label Title">  
     <option class="custom-option-class">Here goes the option to select</option>                                                                          
  </optgroup>
 </select>
```

Here is the link, https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add disable attribute to that option tag which you don't want to select

```
<select>
  <option disabled> CITY 1 </option>
  <option> City 1 branch A </option>
  <option> City 1 branch B </option>
  <option> City 1 branch C </option>
  <option disabled> CITY 2 </option>
  <option> City 2 branch A </option>
  <option> City 2 branch B </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use both `selected` and `disabled` attributes on an `<option>` element in case you wanted to have a sort of an inline label to give basic instructions without letting the user to select it.

`<optgroup>` works great too.

Answer (score -1):

Amid the many responses. It depends on what you want to do with the first option. If you want to display it as some sort of a guide. Say for example option 1 is "Select City" but you don't want users to select it.

```
 <option style={{display: "none"}}>Select City</option>
```

By using the above code, Select City would be the default option. But users will not be able to select it from the options.
Using disable will not render the default, nor be selectable.
You might consider an if statement if you want to disable the option conditionally.