# How to show disable HTML select option in by default?

Tags: html, html-select

I am new to HTML and PHP and want to achieve a drop-down menu from the mysql table and hard-coded too. I have multiple select in my page, One of them is

```
<select name="tagging">
    <option value="">Choose Tagging</option>
    <option value="Option A">Option A</option>
    <option value="Option B">Option B</option>
    <option value="Option C">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Problem is now that user can also select "Choose Tagging" as his tagging but i only want to provide him to chose from available three. I used disable as

```
<select name="tagging">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled">Choose Tagging</option>
    <option value="Option A">Option A</option>
    <option value="Option B">Option B</option>
    <option value="Option C">Option C</option>
</select>
```

But now "Option A" became the default one. So i want to set "Choose Tagging" as by default and also want to disable it from selection. Is it a way to do this. Same thing need to be done with other select which will fetch data from Mysql. Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: how about add a click event on the select to disable the first option.

Comment: You have to fix syntax error - value=""disabled should be disabled="disabled" + remove odd closing </select> tags

Comment: @Evgeniy oops that  </select> belongs to other part of my code

Comment: @AnkitSharma i'be edited your code - you had </select><select><option>...<option> </select>

Comment: @Evgeniy thanx.....  </select> got copied from my code by mistake.

Comment: @DavidSmith my task is done but still want to know what is click event. Is it by using form?

Answer (score 419, accepted):

use

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose Tagging</option>
```

Comment: You don't need to put the `true` or `disabled` values. you can get by doing `<option selected disabled>Choose Tagging</option>`

Comment: @SamEaton,it just makes the code to follow the valid XHTML syntax,else in HTML5 you can neglect it.

Comment: You should set the value="" so if you also have required then an error will be raised to choose from the dropdown, otherwise a empty value gets passed even though nothing was selected.     `<option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="">Choose Tagging</option>`

Comment: Technically `selected="true"` is invalid in html5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588336/9996381

Answer (score 65):

Use `hidden`.

```html
<select>
   <option hidden>Choose</option>
   <option>Item 1</option>
   <option>Item 2</option>
</select>
```

This doesn't unset it but you can however hide it in the options while it's displayed by default.

Comment: This looks fancy.

Comment: This is pretty useful! Thanks!

Comment: The `hidden` attribute has no effect on `<option>` elements in Safari. https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_hidden

Answer (score 52):

In `HTML5`, to select a disabled option:

```
<option selected disabled>Choose Tagging</option>
```

Answer (score 15):

Electron + React.

Let your two first options look like this.

```
<option hidden="true">Choose Tagging</option>
<option disabled="disabled" default="true">Choose Tagging</option>
```

First to display when closed.

Second to display first when the list opens.

Answer (score 9):

I know you ask how to disable the option, but I figure the end users visual outcome is the same with this solution, although it is probably marginally less resource demanding.

Use the [optgroup](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/optgroup.html) tag, like so :

```
<select name="tagging">
    <optgroup label="Choose Tagging">
        <option value="Option A">Option A</option>
        <option value="Option B">Option B</option>
        <option value="Option C">Option C</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, OP need it to be selected by default https://jsfiddle.net/tomsihap/5xm7grnb/

Answer (score 7):

Another SELECT tag solution for those who want to keep first option blank.

```html
<label>Unreal :</label>
<select name="unreal">
   <option style="display:none"></option>
   <option>Money</option>
   <option>Country</option>
   <option>God</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
            <select name="dept" id="dept">
                <option value =''disabled selected>Select Department</option>
                <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
                <option value="electronics">Electronics</option>
                <option value="aidt">AIDT</option>
                <option value="civil">Civil</option>
            </select>
```

use "SELECTED" which option you want to select by defult.
thanks

Comment: This guidance was already posted on this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997841/2943403  Your answer adds no new value to the page and only contributes to page bloat.

Answer (score 4):

```
 selected disabled="true"
```

Use this. It will work in new browsers

Answer (score 4):

we can disable using this technique.

```
<select class="form-control" name="option_select">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select option </option>
  <option value="Option A">Option A</option>
  <option value="Option B">Option B</option>
  <option value="Option C">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery to fill your select element, you can use this:

**html**

```
<select id="tagging"></select>
```

**js**

```
array_of_options = ['Choose Tagging', 'Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C']

$.each(array_of_options, function(i, item) {
    if(i==0) { sel_op = 'selected'; dis_op = 'disabled'; } else { sel_op = ''; dis_op = ''; }
    $('<option ' + sel_op + ' ' + dis_op + '/>').val(item).html(item).appendTo('#tagging');
  })
```

This will allow the user to see the first option as a disabled heading ('Choose Tagging'), and select all other options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this should help....:)

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value=""selected="true" disabled="disabled"> Select</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will **hide** the option for you this **easier** that to make a other dropdown box

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose Tagging</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set which option is selected by default like this:

```
<option value="" selected>Choose Tagging</option>
```

I would suggest using javascript and JQuery to observe for click event and disable the first option after another has been selected:
First, give the element an ID like so:

```
<select id="option_select" name="tagging">
```

and the option an id :

```
<option value="" id="initial">Choose Tagging</option>
```

then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('option_select').observe(click, handleClickFunction);
```

Then you just create the function:

```
function handleClickFunction () {

if ($('option_select').value !== "option_select") 
{
   $('initial').disabled=true; }
}
```