# html select as input to mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

My previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033922/how-to-show-disable-html-select-option-in-by-default) got solved but know i want to use html select value as input to another mysql query. My code so far -

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pwd","db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select eid from tbl1 order by eid;");
    ?>
    <select id="eid" size="1">                                      
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose eid</option>        
<?
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
    <option value="<? echo $row_list['eid']; ?>"<? if($row['eid']==$select){ echo "selected"; } ?>>
    <?echo $row['eid'];?>
    </option>

<?

    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <select name="tagging">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose tagging</option> 
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    </select>
<?
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select  distinct val from tbl2 where val!='' order by val;");
?>
    <select id='val'>
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose val</option> 
<?

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
    <option value="<? echo $row_list['val']; ?>"<? if($row['val']==$select){ echo "selected"; } ?>>
    <?echo $row['val'];?>
    </option>
<?

    }
    ?>
    </select>
<?  
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now the output window have three html select, i want to pass this three value in mysql select query to show some result. But don't know how to do it. All kind of advice are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you need to include in your web script pages.

1. All input fields should be enclosed in a `<form` object.
2. All input fields that should go to server *must* have `name="value"`
   defined.
3. Form *must* have `action="url"` defined, to submit to a different
   web page.
4. Scripting language in the server, should read these `name=value`
   pairs and based on your condition, should pass to database engine to
   store in a table.

Comment: 2. On `<select id="eid">`: It won't be recognized by the server script unless you include a `name` attribute's value to it.

Comment: My final code got too much changed, used Ajax and much more stuff but at the end used Form for initial query, so +1`.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you wrap those 3 `<select></select>` into a `<form>` tag and add action and method attributes such as `<form action="file_to_handle_select_data.php" method="POST">` and than in `file_to_handle_select_data.php` run the queries from `$_POST` array.