# Requiring dropdown selection in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Using "required" on a dropdown form element with a "disabled" selection works in Firefox to prevent users from submitting a form without selecting something from the dropdown list, but not in Chrome. Can you help?

```
<select id="topic" class="form-control" required="required">
      <option disabled selected>select genre</option>
      <option>All genres (whatever works)</option>
      <option>boogers</option>
      <option>cheese</option>
      <option>dumplings</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">select genre</option>
```

src: [How to show disable HTML select option in by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033922/how-to-show-disable-html-select-option-in-by-default)

Comment: It does work for me in chrome. I'm using the 37.0.2062.124 m-64bit version. I can't reselect "select genre".

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'm giving incomplete information. The problem is that it lets me click the Submit button in my full form and follow through with the action attached to Submit, if I skip it without selection an option. In Firefox, it tells me I have to complete that field first.

Comment: I would use some client-side validation (js) and serverside (php) for this. Maybe firefox does this automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Meteor (javascript), so that's the route I decided to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working just add `value=""` to your default option. This answer provides some HTML5 documentation on the matter.

[Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5/6048891#6048891)