# Option tag disable property

Tags: html, reactjs, select

I have a `<select>` tag section in which I want some if the options to be disabled. I have tried using both `disabled="false"` and `disabled="true"`

No matter which I use, all options are appearing as disabled.

Here is my code:

```
<select className="form-control " onChange={this.drugsChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.drug_type}>
   <option value='-1' disabled="true">Select Medication Class</option>
   <option value='Medication Clause A' disabled="false"> Medication Class A</option>
   <option value='Medication Clause B' disabled="false"> Medication Class B</option>
   <option value='Medication Clause C' disabled="true"> Medication Class C</option>
</select>
```

I want Medication Class A and Medication Class B to be not disabled

Comment: What do you mean by "I am having an select Tag in select tag". Is it nested? If yes, can you post the that markup too?

Comment: Just removed the `disabled` specifier completely from the tags you want to be enabled. EX: .`<option value='Medication Clause A'> Medication Class A</option>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make some options in a select menu "unselectable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316540/make-some-options-in-a-select-menu-unselectable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey just try disabled for those which you want to be disabled and no need of giving the disabled key for which you want not to be disabled.

```
<select className="form-control " onChange={this.drugsChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.drug_type}>
   <option value='-1' disabled>Select Medication Class</option>
   <option value='Medication Clause A'> Medication Class A</option>
   <option value='Medication Clause B'> Medication Class B</option>
   <option value='Medication Clause C' disabled> Medication Class C</option>
</select>
```

try this if it is not working you can give `disabled={true}`

Comment: i need with attribute false also

Comment: by removing disabled, it  will work,  need with disable false attribute

Comment: disabled={true}  for disabled options and disabled={flase} for other options should work.

Comment: <option value='Medication Clause C' disabled={medicationclassenable ? {false} : {true}}> Medication Class C</option>
I am trying to keep like this showing error

Comment: use this(medicationclassenable) directly inside disabled instead of ternary operator  
 disabled={medicationclassenable}

Answer (score 0):

Working codesandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wm72wqvw4).

`disabled` doesn't needs boolean value to be set. Mention of it alone dictates `option` tag to be disabled. In react, if you want to have a conditional check, you can do something like

```
 <select className="form-control">
    <option value="-1" disabled={counter !== 0} selected>
        Select Medication Class
    </option>
    <option value="Medication Clause A" disabled={counter === 0}>
        {" "}
        Medication Class A
    </option>
    <option value="Medication Clause B"> Medication Class B</option>
    <option value="Medication Clause C" disabled={counter === 0}>
        {" "}
        Medication Class C
    </option>
</select>
```

Assuming `counter` is a state variable.

In your present case, just doing disabled will suffice.

```
<option disabled selected>
  Select Medication Class
</option>
```